# Merge CSS - Breaks admin page css

Tags: magento-1.9, css

I seem to be having a problem with the merge css function on magento, when i do this the admin panel css seems to  break, I've tried uploading the admin folders again but its still the same. As soon as i turn merge css off, it's fine.

I tried clearing cache etc but no joy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merging CSS has some problems. For us https://github.com/fooman/speedsteradvanced solves most of the problems.

If you don't want to have a plugin for this, make sure, that the CSS files are error free. Every command ends in a ; and so on.

Comment: I thought it had worked, but unfortunately not. The extension is working fine, but when i enable css it'll again break the page. I can exclude any file from this, so i presume the css under admin? Would you know what one that is?

Comment: I would run a CSS validator over all files and find the broken one.-

Comment: I've just done a check and throughout the site i have 300 errors, could these errors also cause a decrease in website speed?

Comment: yes. Browsers have to fix these errors and interpert your CSS. not only makes it the site slower, but you can have different results in different browser (even more, beside the differences in browsers)